# How declare ROS subscriber inside a class?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am publishing images to another node and while publishing I am also subscribing a string. When that string is true I will save the image of the published data at that moment. I am having some trouble because of the following error: `no match operator '='` for the subscriber which I don't understand why.

```
/home/rrcam/catkin_ws/src/image_pub/src/im_pub_sub.cpp: In constructor ‘Node::Node()’:
/home/rrcam/catkin_ws/src/image_pub/src/im_pub_sub.cpp:47:73: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘image_transport::Subscriber’ and ‘ros::Subscriber’)
             sub = nh_.subscribe("/chatter",1, &Node::imageCallback, this);
                                                                         ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/image_transport/image_transport.h:39:0,
                 from /home/rrcam/catkin_ws/src/image_pub/src/im_pub_sub.cpp:2:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/image_transport/subscriber.h:61:7: note: candidate: image_transport::Subscriber& image_transport::Subscriber::operator=(const image_transport::Subscriber&)
 class Subscriber
       ^~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/image_transport/subscriber.h:61:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ros::Subscriber’ to ‘const image_transport::Subscriber&’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/image_transport/subscriber.h:61:7: note: candidate: image_transport::Subscriber& image_transport::Subscriber::operator=(image_transport::Subscriber&&)
/opt/ros/melodic/include/image_transport/subscriber.h:61:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ros::Subscriber’ to ‘image_transport::Subscriber&&’
image_pub/CMakeFiles/i_pub_sub.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'image_pub/CMakeFiles/i_pub_sub.dir/src/im_pub_sub.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [image_pub/CMakeFiles/i_pub_sub.dir/src/im_pub_sub.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1521: recipe for target 'image_pub/CMakeFiles/i_pub_sub.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [image_pub/CMakeFiles/i_pub_sub.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

The Script is as follows: I don't get it what's wrong. I have also tried using `boost::bind` for binding `this` pointer and `msg` in subscriber callback function:

```
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

class Node{

    public:
        cv::Mat frame1;
        std::string GSpipeline1 = "nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=0 ee-mode=0 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=(string)NV12 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink";
        int count =0;
        ros::NodeHandle nh_;
        ros::Rate loop_rate =10;
        cv::VideoCapture cap1;
        sensor_msgs::ImagePtr msg1;
        image_transport::ImageTransport it;
        image_transport::Publisher pub_frame1;
        image_transport::Subscriber sub;

    public:
        Node():it(nh_),cap1(GSpipeline1, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER){
            if (!cap1.isOpened())
            {
                std::cout << "Failed to open camera1." << std::endl;
                return;
            }
            pub_frame1 = it.advertise("/cam1",1);

            // sub = it.subscribe("/chatter",1, boost::bind(&Node::imageCallback, this));
            sub = nh_.subscribe("/chatter",1, &Node::imageCallback, this);
        }

        ~Node(){

        }

        void imageCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
        {
            std::cout<<"I am here"<<std::endl;
            if(msg->data.getData() == 'true'){
                this->count++;
                cv::imwrite("/home/rrcam/sensor0/img_"+ std::to_string(this->count)+".png",this->frame1);
            }

        }

        void start(){

            while (this->nh_.ok()) {
                this->cap1 >> this->frame1;
                // this->cap1.read(this->frame1);
                if (this->frame1.empty()) {
                    ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Failed to capture1 image!");
                    ros::shutdown();
                    break;
                }
                int k = cv::waitKey(20) & 0xff;
                if (k== 27){
                    ROS_ERROR_STREAM("I am trying to close it");
                    ros::shutdown();
                    break;
                }
                this->msg1 = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "bgr8", this->frame1).toImageMsg();
                // cv_bridge::CvImagePtr msg1 = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "bgr8", this->frame1);
                // pub_frame1.publish(msg1);
                this->pub_frame1.publish(msg1);

                // ros::spinOnce();
                this->loop_rate.sleep();

            }

            if(!this->nh_.ok()){
                std::cout<<"trouble with ros node"<<std::endl;
                this->cap1.release();
            }
   
        }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try{
        ros::init(argc, argv, "im_sub_pub_cpp");
        // ros::NodeHandle nh;
        Node n;
        n.start();
        ros::spinOnce(); 
        throw 1;
    }
    catch(const char *e){
        std::cout<<"ROS is shutdown: "<<e<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please let me know what's wrong with the subscriber? Why am I having that error and Can I call the `this` pointer inside subscriber callback as follows in the code in order to increment the `count`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407562/how-declare-ros-subscriber-inside-a-class?/) by [Nagarjun](https://answers.ros.org/users/47555/nagarjun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many problems with the code. Please spend some time going through it line by line.

1. You are subscribing to string data. However, the subscriber is defined using `image_transport::Subscriber`, which is incompatible with string data. In summary, we should use the `ros::Subscriber`.
2. You are trying to perform a string comparison. However, the RHS value is defined as `'true'`. A string must be defined using double quotes such as `"true"`. At present, RHS is nothing but an integer value.
3. The `msg->data` is a string. You do not need to call `getData()` on it. In fact, I don't think that we have `getData()` in the string class. However, we do have `c_str()`, but we don't need `c_str()` for string comparison.
4. For some reason, you are not calling `ros::spinOnce()` inside the `while` loop. It should be called periodically.
5. We do not need `ros::spinOnce()` inside `main` function.

I am having a hard time understanding the design of the code. For example:

1. Why are we making string comparisons?
2. Why do we perform IO operations like writing an image inside a callback?

The code may have conceptual issues. Nevertheless, I fixed the compilation errors. Please see the complete code below:

```
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

class Node
{
public:
  cv::Mat frame1;
  std::string GSpipeline1 =
      "nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=0 ee-mode=0 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), "
      "format=(string)NV12 ! nvvidconv ! "
      "video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, "
      "format=(string)BGR ! appsink";
  int count = 0;
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  ros::Rate loop_rate = 10;
  cv::VideoCapture cap1;
  sensor_msgs::ImagePtr msg1;
  image_transport::ImageTransport it;
  image_transport::Publisher pub_frame1;
  ros::Subscriber sub;

public:
  Node() : it(nh_), cap1(GSpipeline1, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER)
  {
    if (!cap1.isOpened())
    {
      std::cout << "Failed to open camera1." << std::endl;
      return;
    }
    pub_frame1 = it.advertise("/cam1", 1);
    sub = nh_.subscribe("/chatter", 1, &Node::imageCallback, this);
  }

  ~Node()
  {
  }

  void imageCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
  {
    std::cout << "I am here" << std::endl;
    if (msg->data == "true")
    {
      this->count++;
      cv::imwrite("/home/rrcam/sensor0/img_" + std::to_string(this->count) + ".png", this->frame1);
    }
  }

  void start()
  {
    while (this->nh_.ok())
    {
      this->cap1 >> this->frame1;
      if (this->frame1.empty())
      {
        ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Failed to capture1 image!");
        ros::shutdown();
        break;
      }
      int k = cv::waitKey(20) & 0xff;
      if (k == 27)
      {
        ROS_ERROR_STREAM("I am trying to close it");
        ros::shutdown();
        break;
      }
      this->msg1 = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "bgr8", this->frame1).toImageMsg();
      this->pub_frame1.publish(msg1);

      ros::spinOnce();
      this->loop_rate.sleep();
    }

    if (!this->nh_.ok())
    {
      std::cout << "trouble with ros node" << std::endl;
      this->cap1.release();
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "im_sub_pub_cpp");
  Node n;
  n.start();
}
```

On a side note, please feel free to look at the various documentation such as ["Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)"](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29), and ["Writing a Simple Image Publisher (C++)"](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/SubscribingToImages).

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nagarjun](https://answers.ros.org/users/47555/nagarjun/) on 2022-10-13**:
Thank you for pointing out my mistakes @ravijoshi.

1. Yes I have changed the image_transport::Subscriber sub to ros::Subscriber sub, it works 2) We do need ROS::Spinonce, so that callback of subscriber is called.

Overall I have corrected my mistakes as you have provided the solution and the code is working. Thank you for your time.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-14**:
I am glad you made it work. Thank you for the update. By the way, as your question is answered, may I request you to click on the checkmark i.e., ✔icon at the top left side of this answer? It will basically mark the question as answered.